# Entity Framework генерирует ошибки

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Добрый день.

*Visual Studio 2012, EF Version=6.0.0.0*

Ситуация следующая: пока  в модели EF были одни таблицы, все нормально работало. Потом я добавил в модель Хранимую процедуру, сделать функцию импорта.
потом в модели нажал на "Run Custim Tool" 2 раза :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И полезли ошибки типа:

> cannot convert from 'System.Data.Objects.MergeOption' to
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter'

или

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction(string,
>   params System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter[])' has some
>   invalid arguments

Я так понимаю, модель сама должна генерировать обращение к процедурам, но тут она делает это с ошибками. У меня процедура возвращает "Entity",  если это важно.

**Что я делаю неправильно при работе с ХП ?**

Спасибо

Comment: Чем приводить скриншот контекстного меню - лучше бы вы привели где у вас полезли ошибки.

Comment: похожая проблема [ссылка](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19662593/3373603). предлагают установить  EF6 tools for VS2012, или поменять Namespace на `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects`

Comment: Я установил то обновление, перезапустил студию, переустановил ЕF (на всякий случай). Он опродолжает генерирвоать ошибки. вы не знаете .что еще тут нужно сделать?
Пока мне пришлось поменять ссылку на System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects